# Prepared statements not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

I am currently trying to prevent SQL injection with prepared statements, but every time I try to load this code it is failing, what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "Database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `Users`');
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row[0] . "<br>";
}
/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Get error message, print it if the query fails and do whatever the error message wants you to do.

Comment: Try to add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);` to the top of this file.  My guess is that you can't use `get_result` because you don't have the [MySQLnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver installed.

Comment: @RocketHazmat it returned "Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()" I will try installing drivers and see if that works

Comment: @user3273370: Yep.  As I expected.  You need to install `mysqlnd` (search your package manager) for `get_result` to work.  P.S. If you developing, then you might want to change the `display_errors` and `error_reporting` settings in your `php.ini`.  If you can't see the errors, then how can you debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a prepared statement you should bind the results like the following:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `Users`')) {
    $stmt->execute();   
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($param1, $param2...);
    $stmt->fetch();
```

Unfortunately `$stmt->bind_param()` does not accept params array

So you can fetch them with something like this:

```
$stmt->execute();   
$stmt->store_result();
$rows = $stmt->num_rows;
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata(); 

    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) 
    { 
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
    }
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params); 
while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
    foreach($row as $key => $val) 
    { 
        $c[$key] = $val; 
    } 
    $result[] = $c; 
} 

$stmt->close();
```

The array `$result` will contain the result you need.